# Why does node.js give me a parsing error even when I'm not trying to parse?

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling

I'm somehow getting this error:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SyntaxError: Failed to parse value of 607341305994936320votecrate, try passing a raw option to get the raw value
```

And I don't know why... Could anyone explain what this error means or tell me the error in my code? Thanks!

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const port = 300;
const Database = require("@replit/database")
const db = new Database()
const Topgg = require("@top-gg/sdk")

const topggauth = process.env['topgg']
const webhook = new Topgg.Webhook(topggauth)

app.post("/dblwebhook", webhook.listener(vote => {
  const user = vote.user

  if (vote.type == 'test'){
    console.log(vote)
  }
  if (vote.type){
    const weekend = vote.isWeekend
    function weekendcheck() {
      if (weekend == "true"){
        return 2
      }
      if (weekend == "false"){
        return 1
      }
    }
    var uservotec = (user + "votecrate")
    console.log(uservotec)
    db.get(uservotec).then(value => {
      if (!value){
        db.set(uservotec, weekendcheck())
      }
      if (value){
        db.set(uservotec, (weekendcheck() + Number(value)))
      }
    });
  }
}))

app.listen(port, () => console.log('App port online!'));
```

Thanks! Please note that the vote variable is in json format similar to this:

{
user: '607341305994936320',
type: 'test',
query: '',
bot: '981329232456192100',
isWeekend: 'false',
}

Comment: Something is not in proper format.  The specific error is complaining about `607341305994936320votecrate` which appears it could be originating from this `var uservotec = (user + "votecrate")` and perhaps one of the following `db.get()` or `db.set()` causes the error when given that value.

Comment: `var uservotec = (user + "votecrate")` appears to create a weird string that `db.get` cannot handle. What did you intend this to do?

Comment: I intended the variable to be the user ID and votecrate (607341305994936320votecrate) because each user has their own id and the votecrate name specifies votecrate, which I could use to differentiate different items for each user. In later code that was cut off, it works perfectly fine with things like (607341305994936320money) or (607341305994936320count)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find an answer. For some reason, I needed to use JSON.stringify on the variable uservotec... Instead of the code in line 28, use this:

```
var uservotec = JSON.stringify(user + "votecrate")
```

Alternatively, you could convert the user variable to a javascript object.

```
var user = JSON.parse(vote.user)
```

Thank you for everyone's help in helping me find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm inexperienced with node.js but it seems like you're trying to receive data from the database using an ID, but accidentally passing a varchar to an INT column.

If you replace *`db.get(uservotec)`* with  *`db.get(607341305994936320)`* or `db.get('607341305994936320')` and don't get any errors, then maybe you should rethink the line `var uservotec = (user + "votecrate")` because it is concatenating the **float/int** value with the **string** "*votecrate*" resulting in "*607341305994936320votecrate*" which isn't a valid **ID** (maybe I'm wrongly assuming but I hope this helps and feel free to ask for a better explanation).

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I intentionally put the "votecrate" there. Thanks though!

Comment: Sorry, I need to ask! Were you able to fix this issue?

Comment: I wasn't able yet... Thanks for asking!

Comment: Never mind, found an answer